# Sum up time in a pd DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I have the following problem:

I have a pd Dataframe in which there are three columns, a datetime64 timestamp, and two columns each being an integer value. The table basically looks like the following:

| Timestamp | Integer1 | Integer2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-09-06 17:02:37.702173 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-09-06 17:02:38.087692 | 0 | 2 |
| 2022-09-06 17:02:38.706589 | 0 | 1 |
| 2022-09-06 17:02:39.081571 | 0 | 2 |

The two integer columns together represent a state, so there would be two different states in the example 0-1 and 0-2.

In reality, there are several more states and, of course, timestamps. A new entry is written to the table approx. 15 times per second with the current timestamp and state of the system.

The task is now analyzing such a "system log", which includes calculating how much of the total time, the system was in each state.

So for a 20 minute trace and two different states i need a table with two rows for the states and a column with their representative times, adding up to 20 minutes in total.

Is there any way this can be achieved?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain better

Comment: @gtomer I edited it, hope its easier to understand now

Comment: So for example the first row will add to state 0-1 the amount of time between 17:02:37.702173 and 17:02:38.087692?

Comment: Exactly for the state 0-1 i would want to have the amount of time between 2022-09-06 17:02:38.087692 and 2022-09-06 17:02:37.702173, plus the amount of time between 2022-09-06 17:02:39.081571 and 2022-09-06 17:02:38.706589

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `df` your dataframe you could try:

```py
df["Duration"] = df["Timestamp"].diff().shift(-1)
res = df.groupby(["Integer1", "Integer2"], as_index=False)["Duration"].sum()
```

or

```py
res = (
    df["Timestamp"].diff().shift(-1)
    .groupby([df["Integer1"], df["Integer2"]]).sum()
    .rename("Duration").reset_index()
)
```

if you don't want to add a new column to `df`.

Result for your sample

```
                   Timestamp  Integer1  Integer2
0 2022-09-06 17:02:37.702173         0         1
1 2022-09-06 17:02:38.087692         0         2
2 2022-09-06 17:02:38.706589         0         1
3 2022-09-06 17:02:39.081571         0         2
```

is

```
   Integer1  Integer2               Duration
0         0         1 0 days 00:00:00.760501
1         0         2 0 days 00:00:00.618897
```

Comment: So far this seems to do exactly what i wanted, i tried a similar approach but couldn't get it exactly right so thank you very much for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:

```py
import pandas as pd


# == Create an Example DataFrame ==========================================
df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["2022-09-06 17:02:37", 0, 1],
        ["2022-09-06 17:02:38", 0, 2],
        ["2022-09-06 17:02:38", 0, 1],
        ["2022-09-06 17:02:39", 0, 2],
        ["2022-09-06 19:02:38", 0, 1],
        ["2022-09-06 19:02:39", 0, 2],
    ],
    columns=[
        "Timestamp",
        "Integer1",
        "Integer2",
    ],
).astype({"Timestamp": "datetime64[ns]"})

# == Main Logic =========================================================

df.merge(
    (
        (
            df.sort_values("Timestamp")
            .groupby(
                [
                    "Integer1",
                    "Integer2",
                ],
                as_index=False,
            )["Timestamp"]
            .shift(-1)
        )
    )
    .dropna()
    .rename(columns={"Timestamp": "EndTime"}),
    left_index=True,
    right_index=True,
    how="inner",
).assign(TOTAL_TIME=lambda xdf: xdf["EndTime"] - xdf["Timestamp"]).groupby(
    [
        "Integer1",
        "Integer2",
    ],
    as_index=False,
)[
    "TOTAL_TIME"
].sum()

# Expected output:
#    Integer1  Integer2      TOTAL_TIME
# 0         0         1 0 days 02:00:01
# 1         0         2 0 days 02:00:01
```

[image]

Comment: First of, thanks alot for the work and time! But it does not look quite right yet, the amount of time for 0-2 is right, since between 17:02 and 19:02 its the current state, but for 0-1 it should be only about three seconds, not two hours since 0-1 is only active for thee 1-second periods.

Comment: @DRock99 I've changed the values from your original example's dataframe. Have you taken that into consideration?

Comment: ["2022-09-06 17:02:39", 0, 2],
 ["2022-09-06 19:02:38", 0, 1],
["2022-09-06 19:02:39", 0, 2] If im not mistaken, then the state 0,2 is active between 17:02 and 19:02, so 2 hours, but then state 0,1 is only active for a second after and some seconds before, so two hours for state 0,1 seems wrong!

Comment: @DRock99 both states have the same dates in the example I gave